# Why doesn't Data Factory let me copy data from an OnPremise SQL Server to an Avro in the cloud?

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, avro, on-premises-instances, copy-data

The message that appears is the following:
ErrorCode=AvroFailedToSerializeData,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Serializae Avro Data failed. Message: Name 'GENERIC_COLUMN' contains invalid characters..,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException,Message=Name 'GENERIC_COLUMN' contains invalid characters.,Source=Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro,'

The problem arises that those columns in string format are not being able to be migrated to the avro.
I have already done migrating from a SQL Server On premise to Avro in the cloud, I like to use Avro because I thought it was more consistent in the integrity of the data than perhaps a csv which is weaker.
What would be the problem?

Comment: The error message says that a column named "GENERIC_COLUMN" contains invalid characters. Try to check if you can find and fix those characters, or write a query that will omit this entries when reading from ADF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Serializae Avro Data failed. Message: Name 'GENERIC_COLUMN' contains invalid characters.

The issue you are getting because the `GENERIC_COLUMN` name might contain some invalid characters like **`-,* and special characters`**.  Arro file only allow [A-Z,a-z,_] in the field names.

In Mapping you can check all fields name for Avro file if it contains special character remove it.

[image]

Also check the schema of your destination Avro file if its incorrect for naming you can correct it.